# (py)spark dataframe repartition across many IDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning

I have a HUGE table, where my spark job keeps crashing. I want to repartition it. I have two variables (`id`, `time`) where I need to ensure that all rows with a given `id` will be parittioned to the same worker. But I have hundreds of millions of unique IDs. **I want pyspark to evenly spread the data, but respecting that for a given ID all rows should be on one worker.** Can I simply do :

`df.repartition("id")`

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition.html), seems to suggest so. But I am wondering whether spark will now partition the job into hundreds of millions of subsets and only send one subset (i.e. data of one `id`) to the each worker at a time. This would be very inefficient of course.

I am using Spark 2.4.0-cdh6.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `explain` to see what spark does when you call `repartition`:

```py
>>> spark.range(20).repartition("id").explain()
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200)
+- *(1) Range (0, 20, step=1, splits=8)
```

`Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200)` means shuffling the data into 200 partitions. The partition a row ends up in is determined by doing `id.hashCode() % 200`. If you do not have a skew in your data, the distribution should be pretty even. 200 is the default value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` that determines how many partitions are generated after a shuffle. To change that value to say 400, you can either change the value of the config be doing `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 400)` or do `repartition(400, "id")`. Indeed, if you have a lot of data, 200 might not be enough.

Comment: After repart...400 and the join aggr youwill get 200 unless expressly set cia shufflepartitions.